# Manual shows different settling time for an amplifier than its datasheet?

Tags: operational-amplifier

This transducer manual claims INA110 amplifier has 20 microseconds settling time:

http://www.ohtegiken.co.jp/wp/wp-content/uploads/manual_zoc33man_1007.pdf

But when I check the data sheet for the opamp, it says 4 microseconds:

http://datasheet.octopart.com/INA110KP-Texas-Instruments-datasheet-17021610.pdf

Why can this be? Are they assuming a particular gain? There is a gain-settling time curve on data sheet.
What can be the reason?

Comment: There is a gain-settling time curve on data sheet. What can be the reason?

Comment: Your first link is a whole manual.  No, I'm not going to read thru the whole thing to find where in there they mention settling time of a INA110.

Comment: it is pdf and u can search the keyword in 2 seconds. not hard really..

Comment: Without looking, the test conditions for specifications in a data sheet are always given.  When they wander because of some other parameter, there's often a graph showing the effect further down.  Reading the test conditions routinely and reading/understanding the WHOLE datasheet becomes very important for important projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is a gain-settling time curve on data sheet. What can be the
>   reason?

The settling time depends on the gain (datasheet page 3)

```
Settling Time:
0.1%, G = 1 VO = 20V Step 4 * * µs
G = 10 2µs
G = 100 3µs
G = 200 5µs
G = 500 11µs
```

The datasheet figure of 4uS is for a gain of 1 and settling to 0.1% of a VOut of 20v.  I.e. it is under very specific conditions.

The manual is talking about the INA110 in a particular application.  A higher gain may be being used or a different definition of settling might be being used.  Maybe they have an output of 1v (so wobbling voltage will be proportionally bigger).  Maybe they have a tighter definition of settled (perhaps 0.05%).

Answer (score 1):

Since maximum bandwidth, BW occurs at unity gain, G and visa versa. All feedback amplifiers that are variable gain and unity gain stable use an internal 1st order LP filter, where the G-BW product is thus constant.

- At a maximum gain of 500 here, the max. settling time is actually 25 us to 0.01% for a 20V step on Vo in the datasheet of the INA110.
- The rise time and settling time are proportional to gain but the settling time is not linear. This property of settling time appears to be proportional to some logarithm of gain.